# Mysql/PHP/ADODB - echoing SELECT command returns column name and other characters

Tags: php, mysql, ado

I'm having a 'mare trying to get some simple data from my MySQL database.

Executing the following command in phpMyAdmin works fine:

```
SELECT coords FROM btDCSimpleMapMarkers WHERE bID = 152
```

[image: http://i44.tinypic.com/nywy0g.png]

but when I attempt the same in PHP (where bID is dynamically substituted):

```
echo $db->query("SELECT coords FROM btDCSimpleMapMarkers WHERE bID = {$bID}");
```

I get this:

```
"coords
"
"coords
   "55.8858884,-3.5473646","56.1962574,-4.7451167","58.1476532,-5.2027190","55.9714768,-3.1769557","57.6809791,-4.3305414","55.9409414,-3.5107965","56.2444546,-4.2167933","55.5162577,-4.3799082","57.1417936,-2.0930123","55.9699585,-3.1853694","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","55.6459257,-3.1714130","55.8614198,-3.0658253","55.9433622,-3.0590451","55.9563443,-2.7912248","55.8533561,-4.3041345","55.2410909,-4.8555597","55.8577681,-4.2443929","55.8781498,-4.2898555","57.1426478,-2.1232869","56.8705582,-5.4453786","56.1884131,-4.4899996","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","55.9717258,-3.1931145","55.9491408,-2.7235834","55.8922571,-3.0575724","57.0761811,-2.7793013","56.1888841,-3.0137383","55.6956709,-3.3806546","57.4871048,-4.2490284","56.4125195,-5.4727019","56.0751328,-3.4419449","58.4337677,-3.0813735","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0"
"
```

I don't know where the extra stuff at the beginning is coming from (especially the column name). The field contains one long string, and the column type is VARCHAR(20000).

Any help would be appreciated, cos I'm stumped!

Comment: What DB library are you using for this `$db` object? A query call usually doesn't return data directly - they return a statement handle which you use to retrieve individual rows. You're most likely echoing out an object, which is politely auto-stringing the query results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be trying to echo the mysql result directly.

What you need to do is use mysql_fetch_array() to get each row of data and then echo that.

This is how I would do it:

```
$sql = "SELECT coords FROM btDCSimpleMapMarkers WHERE bID = 15";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['coords'] . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that was the issue.